# Why are my objects overlapping in my p5.js project?

Tags: javascript, physics, p5.js

I'm working on a project where I simulate physics with balls.
Here is [the link to the p5 editor](https://editor.p5js.org/titoineis/sketches/ls4ku7eX-) of the project.

My problem is the following, when I add a lot of ball (like 200), balls are stacking but some of them will eventually collapse and I don't know why.

Can somebody explain why it does this and how to solve the problem ?

Thanks.

Here is the code of the sketch.

```
document.oncontextmenu = function () {
    return false;
}

let isFlushing = false;
let isBallDiameterRandom = false;
let displayInfos = true;
let displayWeight = false;
let clickOnce = false;

let FRAME_RATE = 60;
let SPEED_FLUSH = 3;
let Y_GROUND;
let lastFR;

let balls = [];

function setup() {
    frameRate(FRAME_RATE);
    createCanvas(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    Y_GROUND = height / 20 * 19;
    lastFR = FRAME_RATE;
}

function draw() {
    background(255);

    if (isFlushing) {
        for (let i = 0; i < SPEED_FLUSH; i++) {
            balls.pop();
        }

        if (balls.length === 0) {
            isFlushing = false;
        }
    }

    balls.forEach(ball => {
        ball.collide();
        ball.move();
        ball.display(displayWeight);
        ball.checkCollisions();
    });

    if (mouseIsPressed) {
        let ballDiameter;

        if (isBallDiameterRandom) {
            ballDiameter = random(15, 101);
        } else {
            ballDiameter = 25;
        }

        if (canAddBall(mouseX, mouseY, ballDiameter)) {
            isFlushing = false;
            let newBall = new Ball(mouseX, mouseY, ballDiameter, balls);

            if (mouseButton === LEFT && !clickOnce) {
                balls.push(newBall);
                clickOnce = true;
            }

            if (mouseButton === RIGHT) {
                balls.push(newBall);
            }
        }
    }

    drawGround();

    if (displayInfos) {
        displayShortcuts();
        displayFrameRate();
        displayBallCount();
    }
}

function mouseReleased() {
    if (mouseButton === LEFT) {
        clickOnce = false;
    }
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode === 32) {//SPACE
        displayInfos = !displayInfos;
    }

    if (keyCode === 70) {//F
        isFlushing = true;
    }

    if (keyCode === 71) {//G
        isBallDiameterRandom = !isBallDiameterRandom;
    }

    if (keyCode === 72) {//H
        displayWeight = !displayWeight;
    }
}

function canAddBall(x, y, d) {
    let isInScreen =
        y + d / 2 < Y_GROUND &&
        y - d / 2 > 0 &&
        x + d / 2 < width &&
        x - d / 2 > 0;

    let isInAnotherBall = false;

    for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
        let d = dist(x, y, balls[i].position.x, balls[i].position.y);

        if (d < balls[i].w) {
            isInAnotherBall = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isInScreen && !isInAnotherBall;
}

function drawGround() {
    strokeWeight(0);
    fill('rgba(200,200,200, 0.25)');
    rect(0, height / 10 * 9, width, height / 10);
}

function displayFrameRate() {
    if (frameCount % 30 === 0) {
        lastFR = round(frameRate());
    }

    textSize(50);
    fill(255, 0, 0);

    let lastFRWidth = textWidth(lastFR);
    text(lastFR, width - lastFRWidth - 25, 50);
    textSize(10);
    text('fps', width - 20, 50);
}

function displayBallCount() {
    textSize(50);
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    text(balls.length, 10, 50);
    let twBalls = textWidth(balls.length);
    textSize(10);
    text('balls', 15 + twBalls, 50);
}

function displayShortcuts() {
    let hStart = 30;
    let steps = 15;
    let maxTW = 0;
    let controlTexts = [
        'LEFT CLICK : add 1 ball',
        'RIGHT CLICK : add 1 ball continuously',
        'SPACE : display infos',
        'F : flush balls',
        'G : set random ball diameter (' + isBallDiameterRandom + ')',
        'H : display weight of balls (' + displayWeight + ')'
    ];

    textSize(11);
    fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < controlTexts.length; i++) {
        let currentTW = textWidth(controlTexts[i]);

        if (currentTW > maxTW) {
            maxTW = currentTW;
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < controlTexts.length; i++) {
        text(controlTexts[i], width / 2 - maxTW / 2 + 5, hStart);
        hStart += steps;
    }

    fill(200, 200, 200, 100);
    rect(width / 2 - maxTW / 2,
        hStart - (controlTexts.length + 1) * steps,
        maxTW + steps,
        (controlTexts.length + 1) * steps - steps / 2
    );
}
```

Here is the code of the Ball class.

```
class Ball {
    constructor(x, y, w, e) {
        this.id = e.length;
        this.w = w;
        this.e = e;

        this.progressiveWidth = 0;
        this.rgb = [
            floor(random(0, 256)),
            floor(random(0, 256)),
            floor(random(0, 256))
        ];
        this.mass = w;
        this.position = createVector(x + random(-1, 1), y);
        this.velocity = createVector(0, 0);
        this.acceleration = createVector(0, 0);

        this.gravity = 0.2;
        this.friction = 0.5;
    }

    collide() {
        for (let i = this.id + 1; i < this.e.length; i++) {
            let dx = this.e[i].position.x - this.position.x;
            let dy = this.e[i].position.y - this.position.y;
            let distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            let minDist = this.e[i].w / 2 + this.w / 2;

            if (distance < minDist) {
                let angle = atan2(dy, dx);
                let targetX = this.position.x + cos(angle) * minDist;
                let targetY = this.position.y + sin(angle) * minDist;

                this.acceleration.set(
                    targetX - this.e[i].position.x,
                    targetY - this.e[i].position.y
                );
                this.velocity.sub(this.acceleration);
                this.e[i].velocity.add(this.acceleration);

                //TODO : Effets bizarre quand on empile les boules (chevauchement)

                this.velocity.mult(this.friction);
            }
        }
    }

    move() {
        this.velocity.add(createVector(0, this.gravity));
        this.position.add(this.velocity);
    }

    display(displayMass) {
        if (this.progressiveWidth < this.w) {
            this.progressiveWidth += this.w / 10;
        }

        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        fill(this.rgb[0], this.rgb[1], this.rgb[2], 100);
        ellipse(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.progressiveWidth);

        if (displayMass) {
            strokeWeight(1);
            textSize(10);
            let tempTW = textWidth(int(this.w));
            text(int(this.w), this.position.x - tempTW / 2, this.position.y + 4);
        }
    }

    checkCollisions() {
        if (this.position.x > width - this.w / 2) {
            this.velocity.x *= -this.friction;
            this.position.x = width - this.w / 2;
        } else if (this.position.x < this.w / 2) {
            this.velocity.x *= -this.friction;
            this.position.x = this.w / 2;
        }

        if (this.position.y > Y_GROUND - this.w / 2) {
            this.velocity.x -= this.velocity.x / 100;
            this.velocity.y *= -this.friction;
            this.position.y = Y_GROUND - this.w / 2;
        } else if (this.position.y < this.w / 2) {
            this.velocity.y *= -this.friction;
            this.position.y = this.w / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to know how you finally solve the problem. Because I've been thinking about it all night ;-)

Comment: Well, I understand the problem. You were right, the order of my calculations are wrong and not precise enough. I manage to solve a bit the probleme but there is still some shaking movement [ https://editor.p5js.org/titoineis/sketches/e_EEgBi_Y ]. The main problem is that I check the box collision not the same time as I manage the balls collisions so it creates a Delta in my balls positions.

Comment: With the new version, you can make an interesting experiment, try to fill two lines with balls: 16 in the base line and 15 in the line above. I see What do you observe? I see a tendency to get balls concentrated on the right side. Strange ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this overlapping happen when the sum of ball masses gets bigger than the elasticity of the balls. At least it seems so. I [made a copy](https://editor.p5js.org/wolf-at-SO/sketches/oUY4M4Bjt) with a smaller pool so it doesn't take so much time to reproduce the problem.

In the following example, with 6 balls (a mass of 150 units) pressing on the base row, we see that the 13 balls in the base row overlap. The base row has a width of ca. 300 pixels, which is only enough space for 12 balls of diameter 25. I think this is showing the limitation of the model: the balls are displayed circular but indeed have an amount of elasticity that they should display deformed instead. It's hard to say how this can be fixed without implementing drawing complicated shapes. Maybe less friction?

[image: already 19 balls produce overlapping in the base row]

BTW: great physics engine you built there :-)

Meanwhile I was able to make another screenshot with even fewer balls. The weight of three of them (eq. 75 units) is sufficient to create overlapping in the base row.

[image: 15 balls are enough to reproduce the issue]

I doubled the size of the balls and changed the pool dimensions as to detedt that there is a more serious error in the engine. I see that the balls are pressed so heavily under pressure that they have not enough space for their "volume" (area). Either they have to implode or it's elastic counter force must have greater impact of the whole scene. If you pay close attention to the pendulum movements made by the balls at the bottom, which have the least space, you will see that they are very violent, but apparently have no chance of reaching the outside.

[image: the balls have not enough space for their size]

Could it be that your evaluation order

```js
balls.forEach(ball => {
    ball.collide();
    ball.move();
    ball.display(displayWeight);
    ball.checkCollisions();
});
```

is not able to **propagate the collisions** in a realistic way?

Comment: Thank You very much for your answer, I think I will be able to solve my problem with what you told me. I understand much more the problematic here and the limitations with my engine. Thnaks again, keep it up !

Comment: @AntoineJoublin Thank *you* for pulling me into the copy function of the p5.js editor :)